# Regex: match only letters or letters with numbers

Tags: regex

How can I create a regex expression that will match only letters or letters with numbers?
I've tried something like `(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+|[A-Za-z]+)`.
The regex should give the following result:

`123a --> true
123 --> false
abc --> true
abc4 --> true`

Comment: In other words, you wish to match a string that contains only letters and digits and contains at least one letter. When expressed that way you can translate the requirement to a regex directly. How do you require a letter? How do you require the string to only contain certain characters?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
^(?i)(?=.*[a-z])[a-z\d]+$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/yyoMpR/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `awk`. If your text file contains the lines:

```
123a
123
abc
abc4
```

Use this one liner:

```
awk '{ if ($0 ~ /[0-9]/ and $0 ~ /[A-Za-z]/) {print $0 " --> true"} else { print $0 " --> false"  }  }' test.txt
```

or pretty it up as:

```
awk '{ 
    if ($0 ~ /[0-9]/ and $0 ~ /[A-Za-z]/) {
        print $0 " --> true"
    } else {
        print $0 " --> false"
    }
}' test.txt
```

Result

```
123a --> true
123 --> false
abc --> true
abc4 --> true
```

Explanation

- check if the line contains a number. If not, print the line with true
- if the line does contain a number, also check if it contains a letter. If so, print the line with true
- otherwise, print false